# Separating the log of a sum

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I know there is no formula to separate the **log** of a **sum**, e.g. $\log(X+Y)$ into two parts, but are there any approximation rules that can allow me to achieve this objective?

$$E_t(1+r_{t+1}^K)=E_t\left[
\dfrac{\frac1{X_{t+1}}\alpha A_0\frac{Y_{t+1}}{K_{t+1}}+Q_{t+1}(1-\delta)}{Q_t}
\right]$$

Suppose we ignore the expectations operator for the moment.

Comment: For a small neighborhood of $X+Y$, you have the Taylor series.

Comment: the difficulty is that it is not really a small neighbourhood, I have now included the equation in the question. log(1+r) is approximately r, but the RHS is difficult to log-linearise.

Comment: Does $\log(x+y)\ge\frac12(\log x+\log y)+\log 2$ count? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\log(X + Y) = \log(X) + \log(1 + Y/X)$, so if either $X$ is small compared to $Y$ or vice versa then you can approximate with a Taylor approximation.

Answer (score 0):

Working in [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4838311/909869) I found that for positive $x,y$ you could approximate:
$$\ln(x+y)\approx \begin{cases} \frac{x^{\frac{1}{\ln(2)}}\ln(x)-y^{\frac{1}{\ln(2)}}\ln(y)}{x^{\frac{1}{\ln(2)}}-y^{\frac{1}{\ln(2)}}}, \quad x\neq y\\ \ln(x)+\ln(2),\quad x=y \end{cases}$$

which is based in this other approximation:
$$\ln(1+e^x) \approx \begin{cases} \frac{x}{1-e^{-\frac{x}{\ln(2)}}},\quad x\neq 0\\ \ln(2),\quad x=0\end{cases}$$

For the last one the [maximum error is below](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=max+%7Cln%281%2Be%5Ex%29-+x%2F%281-e%5E%28-x%2Fln%282%29%29%29%7C) $0.0092$, and the [plot is quite close](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+ln%281%2Be%5Ex%29%2C+x%2F%281-e%5E%28-x%2Fln%282%29%29%29):

[image: comparison of the plots]