# An approximation to $\ln(1+e^x)$ and how to use it for splitting the logarithm of a sum

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, logarithms, approximation, machine-learning

Trying to split the logarithm of the sum of two exponential functions ([this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4835130/909869)), I found the following approximation for the [Softplus function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)#Softplus) $f(x)=\ln(1+e^x)$:

$$\ln(1+e^x) \approx \begin{cases} \frac{x}{1-e^{-\frac{x}{\ln(2)}}},\quad x\neq 0\\ \ln(2),\quad x=0\end{cases}$$

*From now on I will omit the domain issue at $x=0$ for simplicity, but keep it in mind for the following approximations based in this formula.*

And **I want to know if it is a known approximation and how useful it is**. I just added to the Wikipedia for the [Softplus function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)#Softplus), and I am surprised it wasn't mentioned before. The [maximum error is below](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=max+%7Cln%281%2Be%5Ex%29-+x%2F%281-e%5E%28-x%2Fln%282%29%29%29%7C) $0.0092$, and the [plot is quite close](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+ln%281%2Be%5Ex%29%2C+x%2F%281-e%5E%28-x%2Fln%282%29%29%29):

[image: comparison of the plots]

The error figure could be improved using $f(x,a)=\frac{x}{1-e^{-\frac{x}{a}}}$ with $\frac{1}{a}\approx 1.428666$ but it change the value at $x=0$, which for my application was important to keep it as $f(0)=\ln(2)$ (since matches with $\ln(e^0+e^0)$).

With this approximation I could split [LogSumExp(x,y)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp):
$$\ln(e^x+e^y) \approx \frac{xe^{\frac{x}{\ln(2)}}-ye^{\frac{y}{\ln(2)}}}{e^{\frac{x}{\ln(2)}}-e^{\frac{y}{\ln(2)}}}$$

or simply $x+\ln(2)$ when $x\equiv y$, and it works quite good if $e^x+e^y$ is not too close to zero.

[image: comparison]

But unfortunately it was still too complicated for what I was aiming for. Finally I used the Taylor's expansion of $\ln(1+e^x)\approx \ln(2)+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{8}+O(x^4)$ from were I got $\ln(e^x+e^y)\approx \ln(2)+\frac{x+y}{2}+\frac{(y-x)^2}{8}$.

Also leads to the approximation for positive $x,y$:
$$\ln(x+y)\approx \frac{x^{\frac{1}{\ln(2)}}\ln(x)-y^{\frac{1}{\ln(2)}}\ln(y)}{x^{\frac{1}{\ln(2)}}-y^{\frac{1}{\ln(2)}}}$$

*Please remember is undefined at $x=y$, but it just required to be defined piecewise as $\ln(2x)$ or $\ln(2y)$ where they match.*

[image: splitting the logarithm of a sum though approx]

I don't know if these approximation are wide known or useful, for example **for finding the distribution of the sum of Log-Normal random variables (any reference will be appreciated)**.

I played a bit with them and as example I could found the following approximations:
$$\frac{\ln(1+y^{\ln(2)})}{\ln(y^{\ln(2)})}\approx \frac{y}{y-1}$$
when kind of matches for $y>0$ [plot here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+ln%281%2By%5Eln%282%29%29%2Fln%28y%5Eln%282%29%29%2C+y%2F%28y-1%29).

or more interesting:
$$\ln(x+1)\approx \frac{x^{\frac{1}{\ln(2)}}}{\left(x^{\frac{1}{\ln(2)}}-1\right)}\ln(x)$$

I don't know if **some recurrence relation could be developed through it**, but I tried to use it for the Taylor's expansion of $\ln(x)$ at $x=0$ (which is undefined), and it looks like $\frac{\left(x^{\frac{1}{\ln(2)}}-1\right)}{x^{\frac{1}{\ln(2)}}}\text{Taylor}[\ln(x+1)]$ behaves better than the Taylor's expansion of $\ln(x)$ at $x=1$ near $x=0$ ([see the plot here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+ln%28x%29%2C+%28x%5E%281%2Fln%282%29%29-1%29%2F%28x%5E%281%2Fln%282%29%29%29*%28x-x%5E2%2F2%2Bx%5E3%2F3-x%5E4%2F4%2Bx%5E5%2F5-x%5E6%2F6%2Bx%5E7%2F7-x%5E8%2F8%2Bx%5E9%2F9-x%5E10%2F10%29%2C+from+x%3D0+to+2)).

[image: Taylor expansion approximation]

*Added later: Using these formulas I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4884635/909869) that some pretty descent approximations could be done for the logarithm function - [check its plot here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+ln%28x%29%2C+%28x-1%29%2Fx*%28%28x%2Bx%5Eln%282%29%29%2F%281%2Bx%5Eln%282%29%29%29%2C+from+x%3D0+to+50&lang=en):*
$$\ln(x)\approx \dfrac{(x-1)\left(x+x^{\ln(2)}\right)}{x\left(1+x^{\ln(2)}\right)}$$

Another interesting fact of the approximation is that the following function for a real-valued parameter $a>0$:
$$g(a,x) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{a},\quad x=0 \\ \displaystyle{\frac{x}{1-e^{-ax}}},\quad x\neq 0 \end{cases}$$
could be a smooth approximation for the [ramp function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramp_function) $\frac{x+|x|}{2}$ that can be arbitrarily close as $a\to\infty$ (the maximum absolute error is $1/a$), as you could check in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eeukap62rm).

[image: Rectifier approximation]

Also, the derivative:
$$g'(a,x)=\begin{cases} \frac12,\quad x=0\\ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(a,x),\quad x\neq 0\end{cases}$$
makes a nice smooth approximation of the unitary step function, and also tells you that the slope of $g(a,x)$ at $x=0$ is always $\frac12$ for finite  $0<a<\infty$.

But I don't know why they are not listed as examples for the Wikipedia pages of [Rectifier functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) neither as [Sigmoid functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function), and I don't know if it has been used already as a ReLU function.

[image: sigmoid g]

Comment: I believe there are some min-sum functions used to normalize belief-propagation algorithms that are similar to your problem.

Comment: Is your question about the recurrence?

Comment: This place is not for discussion about Wikipedia, but I may get more of your attention here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:No_original_research. _If you discover something new, Wikipedia is not the place to announce such a discovery._ Maybe after this post has received enough verification and discussion we can cite it on Wiki (or better yet, someone has found a source). If you can defend that this is a routine calculation https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia:CALC maybe you can save the edit. Personally I do not agree though.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being a little harsh, but even this post itself seems to me more like an announcement of your research instead of a question. I feel like you got too excited for the new discovery and can't wait to share it everywhere. But if no one has found a source for this approximation yet, either it is new, or it is not useful. Note none of the people edited your approximation on Wiki has provided a source, and those edits are themselves questionable. I can only think this approximation saves a computation of $\ln$, but other than that I don't see how it is better than the original softplus.

Comment: @X-Rui I placed it in the talk section such more experience people could add it after testing if it is usefull as a variant for the ReLu function.

Answer (score 2):

From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3227686/248217):

$\ln(x)=2\sum_{m=1}^\infty {\dfrac{(\frac{x-1}{x+1})^{2m-1}}{2m-1}}$

We may then have:

$\ln(x+y)=\ln(x)+\ln\left(1+\dfrac{y}{x}\right)=\ln(x)+2\sum_{m=1}^\infty {\dfrac{(\frac{y}{2x+y})^{2m-1}}{2m-1}}$

We can without loss of generality specify $x\ge y$, in which case the maximum error occurs when $x=y$ if we truncate the series after finitely many terms. But even here, $\ln(x+x)-\ln(x)=\ln(2)$ is matched to five decimal places ($0.6931346...$ versus the actual value $0.693147...$) with five terms in the series.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wasn't aware of this expansion. I tried it [here in Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=contourplot%5B2+%28y%5E9%2F%289+%282+x+%2B+y%29%5E9%29+%2B+y%5E7%2F%287+%282+x+%2B+y%29%5E7%29+%2B+y%5E5%2F%285+%282+x+%2B+y%29%5E5%29+%2B+y%5E3%2F%283+%282+x+%2B+y%29%5E3%29+%2B+y%2F%282+x+%2B+y%29%29+%2B+log%28x%29%2C%7Bx%2C+0%2C+10%7D%2C%7By%2C+0%2C+10%7D%5D) for $m=5$ and looks good when $x$ is not near zero. How the approx. of the question behaves compared with yours on accuracy?

Comment: I recommend $x\ge y$ for best accuracy, since that can be chosen wlog. So only the lower right portion of the graph need be applied. With $\ln(1+y/x)$ cortect to five or more decimal places for $0\le y/x\le 1$, we would not easily see the error in this region of the graph.